# How to make javascript confirm box from asp:buttonfield?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, buttonfield

I'm having a hard time getting a javascript confirm box from asp:buttonfield:

This is the original code of the Gridview, however buttonfield does not seem to accept "onClientClick"

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNavios" runat="server"  onrowcommand="gvNavios_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField runat="server" ButtonType="Button" Text="delete" CommandName="Eliminar" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So I tried asp:Linkbutton instead:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="eliminar" CommandName="delete" runat="server" Text="delete"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However this way I cannot get which row was clicked as e.commandargument is not filled

The C# code-behind:

```
 protected void gvNavios_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    string currentCommand = e.CommandName;
    int currentRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    string imo = gvNavios.Rows[currentRowIndex].Cells[3].Text;

    if (currentCommand.Equals("delete"))
    {
        eliminarNavio(imo);
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

}

I appreciate one of the following: Insert javascript in asp:button, or get Row number from linkbutton.

Comment: Is this a typo or did you forget /> in  <asp:ButtonField ?

Comment: Is this a typo or you are using a wrong name. Its `OnClientClick` not `OnClickClient`

Comment: @jashwant In the code is corect :) Good thing about IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the CommandArgument to the LinkButton and provide some index (the object ID will be the best).

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="eliminar" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="delete" runat="server" Text="delete"/>
```

Comment: I posted a sample code. You are deleting the navio based on the text in the cell with index 3, right? What does it contain? the name? id?

Comment: seems to be working! Now e.commandargument returns the value of the "ID" field.

Answer (score 0):

Porque no usas un templatefield ?, creo es mas facil

why dont u use a templatefield ?¿

inside the **RowDataBound** :

First create  a templatefield, then inside the templatefield insert an imageButton, Call it img_borrar(commandName).

Then in the rowcommand, find it, set the index (CommandArgument), set some style, and the java comfirmation:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim boton_borrar As ImageButton = CType(e.Row.Cells(1).FindControl("img_borrar"), ImageButton)
                boton_borrar .CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString
                boton_borrar .Style("cursor") = "hand"
                boton_borrar .Attributes.Add("onClick", "return window.confirm(' ¿Desea borrar este registro? ');")


            End If
```